# QGIS 3.22 sorting by attributes does not work in gpkg-files

Tags: qgis, geopackage, sorting

[image]Since I updated from QGIS 3.16 to 3.22 I have the following problem in attribute tables: in gpkg files the sorting option (alphabetical) does not work - sometimes!

I tried it with projects in qgz- or qgs-format. It happens with point-layers and with polygon layers.

Mostly the problem occurs in gpkg layers, seldom also in shapefiles. The problem only happens in string fields, not in integer/real fields. What is the problem, is it a bug?

Now I added a screenshot. In my OS ubuntu 20.04 up to QGIS 3.16 I sorted by single click, everytime it worked, when I clicked single on the top of a field in the attribute table. Now for example in this table a single click (or double click) works for the field "name_lat", but not for the field "name_d", neither with "jahr". All three fields are string fields. With fid it works.

Now I tried another way: there is a possibility for sorting, but more complicated. When I click on the top of the attribute table, choose context menu, choose sorting. Then I can choose the field for sorting the attribute table. So it works, but it is really complicated. Up to QGIS 3.16 it worked just by one click on the field name that is relevant for me.

Look here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47613

Comment: You mean sort by double-clicking the column name?

Comment: I have done a quick test in 3.16 and 3.22 and the data sets I used sorted fine, doesn't mean there isn't an issue.

Comment: Yeah, you probably have to provide a bit more context: how does you attribute table look like, how do you sort and how does the result look like?

Comment: I also think there's something going on with the attribute table sort. Sometimes I can double-click the column name and nothing happens in 3.24

Comment: I’ve never needed to double-click a column head to sort in an attribute table, but I can confirm that this sorting problems exists in 3.24. I didn’t notice this in previous versions.

Comment: I had a table in a layout view that will not sort correctly by a column but will sort correctly by a duplicate of the same column, so agreed there does seem to be an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is fixed in QGIS 3.22.5.